# Android Firebase Recyclerview changes value of wrong item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

What seems to happen is that if a child is changed in Firebase, the recyclerview replaces the topmost item with the changed value.

[image]

For example, if I were to change "Calculus" with "Chemistry", it would replace the entry with Biology, John, 7 PM with Chemistry, John, 8 PM (of course only in the recyclerview itself). The recyclerview is only corrected upon restarting the activity with recreate(). This same issue occurs when onChildRemoved, as the topmost entry gets deleted (in the recyclerview) instead of the one that is actually being deleted from the database.

This issue started appearing when I changed my database reference to look inside "requests" instead of "users."

Here is the method I am using to update my list:

```
private void updateList() {

    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestModel.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            RequestModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestModel.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.set(index, model);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            RequestModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestModel.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the index method:

```
private int getItemIndex(RequestModel request) {

    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        if (result.get(i).key.equals(request.key)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    return index;
}
```

And here is my model:

```
public class RequestModel {

String subject, time, name, key;

public RequestModel() {

}

public RequestModel(String subject, String time, String name, String key) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.time = time;
    this.name = name;
    this.key = key;
 }
 }
```

**EDIT**

onCreate method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    String userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userID).child("requests");

    result = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.request_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adapter = new RequestAdapter(result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();
```

update list points to the method that @Chan Teck Wei added.

And here is the adapter as requested:

```
private List<RequestModel> list;

public RequestAdapter(List<RequestModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public RequestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new RequestViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_items, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RequestViewHolder holder, int position) {

    RequestModel request = list.get(position);

    holder.requestSubject.setText(request.subject);
    holder.requestTime.setText(request.time);
    holder.requestName.setText(request.name);

    holder.itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
            contextMenu.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 0, 0, "Chat");
            contextMenu.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 1, 0, "Report");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView requestSubject, requestTime, requestName;

    public RequestViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        requestSubject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.request_subject);
        requestTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.request_time);
        requestName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.request_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show `result` and adapter implementation too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that your `reference` is pointing to **users/key/requests**. First, you're going to modify your RequestModel class a bit.

```
public class RequestModel {

String subject, time, name, key;
private String mKey;

public RequestModel() {

}

public RequestModel(String subject, String time, String name, String key) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.time = time;
    this.name = name;
    this.key = key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    mKey = key;
}

public String getKey() {
    return mKey;
}
}
```

`setKey()` is used to set the RequestModel object with a unique key fetched from the database. `getKey()` then will be used to identify the object's actual key. It is useful for edit operation.

```
ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            RequestModel request = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestModel.class);
            request.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            result.add(request);
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(result.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            RequestModel request = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestModel.class);
            request.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                if (result.get(i).getKey().equals(request.getKey())) {
                    result.set(i, request);
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            RequestModel request = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestModel.class);
            request.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                if (result.get(i).getKey().equals(request.getKey())) {
                    result.remove(i);
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Personally, this implementation is better than using `notifyDataSetChanged()` within the method `onChildAdded()`. Moreover, the animation is eye candy.

Comment: Thank you, but the data is not updating in real time now; it only updates if I restart the activity. I have added my onCreate method as well, if that is any help

Comment: @HackNode Check if your implementation of `onChildChanged()` is the same.

Comment: I have figured out the problem. When comparing the strings, the "equals()" function should have been used. For example,                                              
                                                                                                                        if (result.get(i).getKey().equals(request.getKey())) {

Comment: @HackNode Oh? Thanks man. I'm used to using Kotlin in Android, hence the mistake. I've approved your edits.